# Write single bean rowise per attribute to csv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm using opencsv and I've got a single model (lets say `Person` with three attributes `name, age, sex`) which I want to store to a csv-file.

It should look like the following:

```
"name";"Jon";
"age";"30";
"sex";"male";
```

The first column contains the property name and the second one contains the value (like a key-value pair).

My implementation looks like the following:

```
writer = new FileWriter("./settings.csv");

StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Person> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<SettingsModel>(writer);
StatefulBeanToCsv<SettingsModel> beanWriter = beanToCsv.build();
beanWriter.write(model);
writer.close();
```

I know that there are some settings available with on `beanToCsv` but I've got no clue how.

If its even possible? 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StatefulBeanToCsv has a standard manner to serialize bean into tabular format.

What you really want is to flatten the bean into Key-Value pair. So the trick should use a [BeanMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) to hold Person bean data. As Person bean has no nested object, we can simply transform it into ValueHolder.key and ValueHolder.value.

Eventually apply this strategy [ColumnPositionMappingStrategy](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/ColumnPositionMappingStrategy.html) in this way:

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<ValueHolder> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
strategy.setType(ValueHolder.class);
strategy.setColumnMapping("key", "value");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("./settings.csv");
StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<ValueHolder> csvBuilder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>(writer);
StatefulBeanToCsv<ValueHolder> beanWriter = csvBuilder.withSeparator(';').withMappingStrategy(strategy).build();
beanWriter.write(content);
writer.close();
```

Full working sample can be accessed [here](https://github.com/t3hr0n/opencsv-transpose/blob/master/src/test/java/Playground.java).

Comment: That was pretty helpful, thanks for the code example!